# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 EXPRESS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, parameters

I'm working with a REST web service in Express and I would like to get an object that contains the hours that I put in parameter.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    var responseObject = { messages: 'OK' };
    res.send(responseObject);
})

router.get('/api/consommation/:heure', function(req, res) {
    var heure = req.query.heure;
    var responseObject = [{
        "heure": "08",
        "prix": "0.1593"
    }, {
        "heure": "09",
        "prix": "0.1593"
    }, {
        "heure": "01",
        "prix": "0.1252"
    }, {
        "heure": "02",
        "prix": "0.1252"
    }, {
        "heure": "03",
        "prix": "0.1252"
    }];

    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(responseObject);
        jsonContent.forEach(function(obj) {
        obj.forEach(function(o) {
            if (o['heure'] == heure) 
                console.log(o);     
        });
    });

    res.json(jsonContent);
});

module.exports = router;
```

So I would like to return my object that contain the hours entered in parameter and its price.

Comment: Can rename your variables in English, so people can understand your code. I had to use google translate to learn `heure` means `hour`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `responseObject` directly and remove inner foreach loop.

```js
heure = 01; 
var responseObject = [
    {
        "heure": "08",
        "prix": "0.1593"
    },
    {
        "heure": "09",
        "prix": "0.1593"
    },
    {
        "heure": "01",
        "prix": "0.1252"
    },
    {
        "heure": "02",
        "prix": "0.1252"
    },
    {
        "heure": "03",
        "prix": "0.1252"
    }
];

responseObject.forEach(function (obj) {
        if (obj['heure'] == heure)
            console.log(obj);
})
```

Comment: It works but always return the first item
I got this error      
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
 What i Should add to my code ?

Comment: Thank You  I saw this link but I cant understand What I add to my code that it can works cause im new in Node here

Comment: When i test this in URL `http://localhost:3000/api/consommation/heure=13` I always get the first item in my array object . and I get this error in my command line : Error Cant set headers after thery are sent  ..
I

Answer (score 1):

The error is there because you are trying to use `JSON.parse` on JS object instead rather than string (that method is for parsing JSON string).

Just drop the line `var jsonContent = JSON.parse(responseObject);` and use `responseObject` directly.

Answer (score 0):

no need to `var jsonContent = JSON.parse(responseObject);` as json is allready parsed.

replace

```
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(responseObject);
```

by

```
var jsonContent =responseObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Final Code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/test', function(req, res){
 var responseObject = {messages : 'OK'};
 res.send(responseObject);
})

router.get('/api/consommation', function(req, res, next){
 var heure = req.param('heure');
 var responseObject = [ 

        { "heure" :"08",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"09",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"10",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"11",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"12",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"13",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"14",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },        
        { "heure" :"15",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },  
        { "heure" :"16",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"17",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"18",
          "prix" : "0.1593"},
        { "heure" :"19",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"20",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"21",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"22",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"23",
          "prix" : "0.1593" },
        { "heure" :"00",
          "prix" : "0.1252" },
        { "heure" :"01",
          "prix" : "0.1252"},
        { "heure" :"02",
          "prix" : "0.1252" },
        { "heure" :"03",
          "prix" : "0.1252" }, 
       { "heure" :"04",
          "prix" : "0.1252" }, 
       { "heure" :"05",
          "prix" : "0.1252" },
       { "heure" :"06",
          "prix" : "0.1252" },
       { "heure" :"07",
          "prix" : "0.1252" },
   
 ];
  responseObject.forEach(function (obj) {
        if (obj['heure'] == heure)
            res.json(obj);
        else
          return next;

  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

And my main problem was i didnt put the 'next' parameter in my function and return it later
THANK YOU ALL